# Connection error rabbitmq using python

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am new using rabbitmq, and I use windows 10. I installed both the rabbitmq-server and the pika library. I was trying to use this tutorial to see how rabbitmq works [tutorial here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html)
I am getting the following error:

```
  File "C:/Users/laysa/Documents/Python Scripts/send.py", line 9, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('127.0.0.1'))

  File "C:\Users\laysa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()

  File "C:\Users\laysa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 414, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)



 File "C:\Users\laysa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 468, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed(maybe_exception)

ConnectionClosed: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5672 failed: timeout
```

I tried to use the solution on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103758/why-cant-i-establish-connection-to-rabbitmq-using-python) but it did not solve my question.

Thank you in advance,
(I am quite new on rabbitmq)

Comment: How do you start _rabbitmq_ _receiver_?

Comment: Your rabbit server is not running or it is not listening to localhost interface (127.0.0.1) or port 5672.  Or you have a software firewall that blocks connections to it.

Comment: @Seer.The I used the code that is provided in the tutorial above. I also change the localhost as this could be the cause of error.

Comment: what happens if you open command line window and try telnet 127.0.0.1 5672     Do you get a timeout, connection failed or a successful connection?

Comment: Can you access the RabbitMQ admin interface in the browser? http://localhost:15672/

Comment: @LutzHorn no, I do not have access to this page. it can not connect to it.

Comment: Where is the RabbitMQ server installed? Is in really installed on your local machine?